# Hide/show individual items inside ngFor

Tags: angular

I need to show / hide part of component. Here is Angular2 example.

```
<li *ngFor=" #item of items " >
  <a href="#" (onclick)="hideme = !hideme">Click</a>
  <div [hidden]="hideme">Hide</div>
</li>
```

Suppose we have only 2 items. Problem here that it works on both items. So it hides and shows div part in **both** components.
It could be perfect if we could have something like this:

```
<li *ngFor=" #item of items " >
   <a href="#" (onclick)="this.hideme = !this.hideme">Click</a>
   <div [hidden]="this.hideme">Hide</div>
</li>
```

So is there some simple way to solve this problem ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017246/angular2-toggle-icons-inside-ngfor Please refer the above link for clear answer

Answer (score 37):

You're `hideme` variable is global. Perhaps you could attach it to the current item:

```
<li *ngFor=" #item of items " >
  <a href="#" (onclick)="item.hideme = !item.hideme">Click</a>
  <div [hidden]="item.hideme">Hide</div>
</li>
```

Otherwise you need to use a dedicated object object from your component. Here is a sample:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items " >
  <a href="#" (onclick)="hideme[item.id] = !hideme[item.id]">Click</a>
  <div [hidden]="hideme[item.id]">Hide</div>
</li>
```

Don't forget to initialize the `hideme` object this way in your component:

```
hideme:<any> = {};
```

**Edit**

If you want to make this work like tabs, you need a bit more work ;-)

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items " >
  <a href="#" (onclick)="onClick(item)">Click</a>
  <div [hidden]="hideme[item.id]">Hide</div>
</li>
```

And to display the clicked element and hide others:

```
onClick(item) {
  Object.keys(this.hideme).forEach(h => {
    this.hideme[h] = false;
  });
  this.hideme[item.id] = true;
}
```

Comment: well it toggles elements but doesn't work like tabs, open one and close another, but any way it's almost the answer )

Comment: I added some code to implement the tab-like behavior ;-) Feel free to tell if it suits your needs ;-)

Comment: @ThierryTemplier Is there is live implementation of this hide and show I have no clue about items in the answers what it contains and how we id works and how It Identify each element to hide sperately

Comment: @ThierryTemplier how to hide items for the first time? when page loads?

Comment: @PratapA.K - Just change this line `<div [hidden]="hideme[item.id]">Hide</div>` to this line `<div [hidden]="!hideme[item.id]">Hide</div>`. Notice the `!` before `hideme..` in the second line

Answer (score 14):

is work for me :

in your compoment decler about hideme as array

```
hideme=[]
```

and in the ngFor do that:

```
<li *ngFor="item of items;let i = index " >
   <a (click)="hideme[i] = !hideme[i]">show/hide</a>
   <div [hidden]="hideme[i]">The content will show/hide</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4):

In component class, declare `hideme` variable (typescript):

```
export class MyPage{
   hideme = {};
   constructor(){
       this.hideme = {}; // init is required
   }
   ...
```

Show/hide control in template:

```
<li *ngFor="item of items " >
   <a (click)="hideme[item.id] = !hideme[item.id]">show/hide</a>
   <div [hidden]="!hideme[item.id]">The content will show/hide</div>
</li>
```

Notes:
`hideme` not required init because `hideme[item.id]` is `undefined` thus `!hideme[item.id]` will `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that shows a plus sign when the parent item is collapsed and switches to a minus sign when it's expanded and shows a list of items that belong to the clicked category. (In your case, this would be the div that contains the things you want to show and hide instead of a list.)

I've achieved this using the **details** and **summary** elements instead of the accordion. These elements are purpose built for this use case.

Using the problem that was presented in this thread: [angular2 toggle icons inside ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017246/angular2-toggle-icons-inside-ngfor)

Here are screenshots of what the collapsed and expanded category looks like:

[Collapsed category with plus sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWvtA.jpg)

[Expanded category with minus sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFdGH.jpg)

This is the template:

```
<ul *ngIf="categoryList && categoryList.length > 0">
        <li *ngFor="let category of categoryList">
            <details>
                <summary>
                    <i class="fa fa-lg expand-icon"></i>
                    <span>{{ category.name }}</span>
                </summary>
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let item of category.yourItemListUnderCategory">{{ item }}</li>
                </ul>
            </details>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I'm using Font Awesome for the plus and minus icons and here's how to toggle them. In your css, add the following styles:

(I'm referencing the icon with the class I assigned it but you can also do
details summary i:before and details[open] summary i:before)

```
details summary .expand-icon:before {
    content: "\f055";
}
details[open] summary .expand-icon:before {
    content: "\f056";
}
```

Note: I'm using a Bootstrap theme for the screenshots but have stripped the class names on the elements to not clutter the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML: 
    (click)="onClick($event)"

Inside de function onClick, you can catch the event and use it like a jquery object, like this:

```
onClick(event){
   $(event.target).siblings('div').toggle(500);
}
```

In this example, I search for the sibling of my target object, you could do that with any object you need.

Answer (score 0):

Add HTML ngFor by passing the values to the function.

```
<ul *ngFor="let ent of entities;let i = index">
  <li>
    <div (click)="showEntity(ent)">
      <h5 class="h5">
        {{ent.values}}
      </h5>
      <p [hidden]="!hideme["ent.id]">
        <span class="play-icon"></span>
        {{ent.name}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

declare variable.

```
 hideme = {};
 entities = [
    { id: 1, values: "Animal", name: "Tiger" },
    { id: 2, values: "Bird", name: "Sparrow" },
    { id: 3, values: "River", name: "Nile" }
  ];
```

initiate it in the constructor and onInit.

```
  constructor() {
    this.hideme = {};
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.entities.forEach(e => {
      this.hideme[e.id] = false;
    });
  }
```

set all values to false.

then onclick .

```
 showEntity(item) {
   Object.keys(this.hideme).forEach(h => {
     this.hideme[h] = false;
   });
   this.hideme[item.id] = true;
 }
```

change flag of that perticular id to true and rest of them will be false

Check stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qppnvq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)!