# angular2 toggle icons inside ngFor

Tags: loops, angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-ng-if

Can some one please let me know how to toggle icons while doing ngFor?

Problem Statement:
I'm using *ngFor to loop through an array and display category names. On click of day I need to open an accordian and show category details (I can do this).
Once accordian opens I need to replace fa-plus icon with fa-minus and vice-versa and I need to do this only for clicked day.

How can I achieve this effectively?

```
this.categoryList = [
{type: 'space', name: 'Space'},
{type: 'energy', name: 'Energy'},
{type: 'comfort', name: 'Comfort'},
{type: 'maintenance', name: 'Maintenance'},
{type: 'reporting', name: 'Reporting'}
];
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="{{category.type}}" *ngFor="let category of categoryList">
    <div data-toggle="collapse" [attr.href]="'#'+'category-'+category.type">
    <div class="title {{category.name}}">{{category.name}}</div>
    <div>
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> //needs to toggle between plus and minus
                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> //needs to toggle between plus and minus
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse" id="category-{{category.type}}">
        //details
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery for accordion?

Comment: @RehbanKhatri Bootstrap!! Accordian is fine and its working !!. Only I need to know how to toggle fa-plus and fa-minus.

Comment: Please show your accordion code, maybe there's a state variable which could be used! :)

Comment: Should it be possible to "open" multiple days?

Comment: do you just need one single `<i>` and than just gtoggle on the class on this one? so it becames `class="fa fa-plus"` or `class="fa fa-minus"` Just conat understand why keeping two `<i>` at the same time.

Comment: I think this is a better answer to your specific question, Summary and Details elements are purpose built for this, rather than indices - http://stackoverflow.com/a/42027647/7511922

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If I understand you right you can have just one `<i>` on the page instead of having two:

**template:**

```
<div *ngFor="let day of daysInAWeek; let i = index">
    <div>{{day}}</div>
    <div>
        <i class="fa" [ngClass]="toggle[i] ? 'fa-plus': 'fa-minus'" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="details">Today is {{day}}</div>
    <button (click)="toggle[i] = !toggle[i]">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

**ts:**

```
daysInAWeek: string[] = ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su']; 
toggle = {};
```

So you can toggle just toggle classes on that  element to be `fa-plus` or `fa-minus`

You can put `(click)="toggle[i] = !toggle[i]` on any html element inside your  `*ngFor` temlpate so it will trigger the toggle on click for related `<i>` element.

Comment: I tried your solution but but its toggling icons for all the categories. Please take a look at attached screen shots. thanks

Comment: yeah, you right. I modified the code so now it should work just for each item using an index

Answer (score 0):

1) You will need a variable that stores which day is currently selected.

```
public SelectedDay:string = null;
```

2) Then on click, set selected day,

```
<div (click)="SelectedDay=day">{{day}}</div>
```

3) Check if selected day is the same day in loop using `*ngIf` or `hidden`

```
<i class="fa fa-plus" *ngIf="SelectedDay!=day" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-minus" *ngIf="SelectedDay==day" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Your final HTML should look like this -

```
<div *ngFor="let day of daysInAWeek">
<div (click)="SelectedDay=day">{{day}}</div>
 <div>
   <i class="fa fa-plus" *ngIf="SelectedDay!=day" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-minus" *ngIf="SelectedDay==day" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </div>
<div class="details">Today is {{day}}</div>
</div>
```

This should work.