# Class Binding when applying it to a *ngFor for an element

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I need some help and for some reason I can't think of how to resolve it

I have an array of objects that I am looping through with *ngFor with

I want to add class binding to a field (description details) in my array but I do not want the action to happen to every 'Detailed Description'

just the one I am working with.  Not sure if this is possible. Hopefully I am making sense.

Currently when I expand 'Detailed Description' Every object that has 'Detailed Description' also expands (Don't want that to happen)!

------HTML-----------

```
<div *ngFor="let n of Entry">
        <ul class="list-group">
         <li>
          <p class="description"> Detailed Description
           <span class="glyphicon" [class.glyphicon-minus- 
           sign]="expandedDetails" [class.glyphicon-plus- 
           sign]="!expandedDetails" (click)="toggleDetails()"></span>
            </p>
            <span class="entryDetails" *ngIf="expandedDetails == true"> 
             {{n.description}}</span>
```

---------TS----------------------

```
toggleDetails() {
this.expandedDetails = !this.expandedDetails;
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide/show individual items inside ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873900/hide-show-individual-items-inside-ngfor)

Comment: You should add the `expandedDetails` flag to the `Entry` class and toggle the flag only for the item that you click: `(click)="n.expandedDetails = !n.expandedDetails"`. The condition for showing the details would be: `*ngIf="n.expandedDetails"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Define toggle variable in ts file

```
 toggle=[]
```

In your html modify your code like this

```
<div *ngFor="let n of Entry;let i =index">
        <ul class="list-group">
         <li>
          <p class="description"> Detailed Description
           <span class="glyphicon" [class.glyphicon-minus- 
           sign]="expandedDetails" [class.glyphicon-plus- 
           sign]="!expandedDetails" (click)="toggle[i]=toggle[i]  "></span>
            </p>
            <span class="entryDetails" *ngIf=" toggle[i]"> 
             {{n.description}}</span>
```

Comment: (click)="toggle[i]=!toggle[i]

Comment: Yes use use index to find the element

Answer (score 1):

You want to use trackby $index on the for-each then you can use this value to pass to toggleDetails. So you will only open the details for that row/item.

Let me get an example