# How to make expandable table rows within an ngFor loop [Angular]?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I've nested tables, when a row is clicked I need to display data underneath the table row. However, the data is being displayed at the end of ngRepeat.

HTML:

```
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive-xl">
  <thead>
    <th> Name </th>
    <th> Place </th>
    <th> Phone </th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

  <tr *ngFor="let data of data1" (click) ="expand()">
        <td> +{{data.name}} </td>
        <td> {{data.place}} </td>
        <td> {{data.phone}} </td>
  <td> {{data.hobbies}} </td>
  <td> {{data.profession}} </td>
 </tr>

 <ng-container *ngIf="expandContent">
    <tr *ngFor="let data of data2">
        <td> {{data.datades.name}} </td>
        <td> {{data.datades.hobbies}} </td>
        <td> {{data.datades.profession}} </td>
 </tr>
 </ng-container>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Component :

```
export class AppComponent  {
expandContent = true;
  data1 =[{
 'name' : 'john',
 'place' : 'forest',
 'phone' : '124-896-8963'
  },{
 'name' : 'Jay',
 'place' : 'City',
 'phone' : '124-896-1234'
  }, {
 'name' : 'Joseph',
 'place' : 'sky',
 'phone' : '124-896-9632'
  },
  ]

 data2 =[{
'whoseData' : 'john',
'datades' : {
'name' : 'john',
'hobbies' : 'singing',
'profession' : 'singer'
 }
 },{
'whoseData' : 'Jay',
'datades' : {
'name' : 'jay',
'hobbies' : 'coding',
'profession' : 'coder'
}
}
]

 expand(){
this.expandContent = !this.expandContent
}
 }
```

When the first row is clicked I would like to display, the data associated with the first row, under it.

Expected result [image]

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j8tpwg)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You would need to make these changes:

1. Include the main row and the corresponding detail rows in the same `ngFor` loop iteration
2. Add an `expanded` property to the `data` objects, instead of having the global `expandContent`
3. Define a method to filter the details of the clicked row

The template could look as follows:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of data1">
  <tr (click)="data.expanded = !data.expanded">
    <td> {{ data.expanded ? '&ndash;' : '+'}} {{data.name}} </td>
    <td> {{data.place}} </td>
    <td> {{data.phone}} </td>
    <td> {{data.hobbies}} </td>
    <td> {{data.profession}} </td>
  </tr>
  <ng-container *ngIf="data.expanded">
    <tr *ngFor="let details of findDetails(data)">
      <td> {{details.datades.name}} </td>
      <td> {{details.datades.hobbies}} </td>
      <td> {{details.datades.profession}} </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

where `findDetails` is defined as:

```
findDetails(data) {
  return this.data2.filter(x => x.whoseData === data.name);
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsxqmk?file=src/app/app.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: This is a great answer! Using this myself!

Comment: Thank for this great answer! Saved my time!

Comment: this is really awesome !!

Comment: I've tried a few different ones (usually requiring css and jquery) and this is the easiest way in Angular, thanks!

Comment: great answer. However, for me it repeats the value of the first column in all subsequent lines. Any idea why it's behaving like that?

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown data is being displayed at the bottom of the table because your `ng-container` is in a separate `div`.  Checkout Bootstrap Collapse and look at the Accordion example to see if it will solve your problem: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/

Comment: [I used this on my tr elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873900/hide-show-individual-items-inside-ngfor)