# Hide/show only one child component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have a list of child components inside a ngFor:

```js
<ng-container *ngFor="let field of fields">
 <button (click)="show = !show">Show</button>
 <ng-container *ngIf="show">
  <app-field [fieldInfo]="field"></app-field>
 </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

I want to only show this specific `app-field` component if `show` is `true`, but this is obviously not the way, because it sets `show` to `true` for all of the rendered components.

My problem is really that I cant show all of the `app-fields` because they turn my app into a slow mess when they are displayed (there will be hundreds of them), s*o I only want to display them when they are needed*.

**How can I toggle the rendering of each specific component on/off uppon click? Or is there som other solution I could look into?**

Comment: You could attach a show variable inside the field object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to only have the component be attached to the DOM when set to be visible. Solved it with the answer in: [Thierry Templier answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36874220/5306142)

Inside parent component:

```js
public showField: any = {};
```

Then in parent component template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let field of fields">
 <button (click)="showField[childField.id] = !showField[childField.id]">Show</button>
 <ng-container *ngIf="showField[childField.id]">
  <app-field [fieldInfo]="field"></app-field>
 </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

This destroys the component when `*ngIf` is `false`, which is what I needed in this situation.

Thanks to @yazan for leading me to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**`show`** variable is global and updating value for show will reflect for all the `app-field` components, Thus You need to determine and specify a show/hide variable for each component individually.

To do that you should add a show member inside the field Object as follow:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let field of fields">
 <button (click)="field.show = !field.show">Show</button>
 <ng-container *ngIf="field.show">
  <app-field [fieldInfo]="field"></app-field>
 </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Also found similar solution, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36874220/4309639)

Comment: This would not stop the component from being inserted into the DOM? Only the content of the component.

Comment: *ngIf will insert any HTML element or component in the DOM  if and only if the condition was true, and that is the main difference between *ngIf and [hidden]

Comment: @thierry-templier s answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36874220/4309639 did it for me.